# "All saves", "For later" and "View answer" (in the interface of the saves) are not translated

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, international-sites, saves

The strings "All saves" and "For later" are not translated on internationalized sites.
These strings have been translated by [traducir.win](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir) for the Japanese and Russian sites.
Nonetheless, they are still in English on the Saves page.

#### Screenshot

> Japanese site:
>
> [image: Screenshot on Japanese site]

> Russian site:
>
> [image: Screenshot on Russian site]

#### Translation strings

- "All saves":

  - Ja: "すべてのセーブ"  https://ja.traducir.win/strings/16355
  - Ru: "Все закладки"  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18043
- "For later":

  - Ja: "あとで読む"  https://ja.traducir.win/strings/16449
  - Ru: "На потом"  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18155

---

#### Added "View answer"

Dec 21, 2022:

I found the same problem with the string "View answer".
This is the string that will be displayed in the list when you "save" the answer.

> [image: View answer]

- Ja: "回答を表示" https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15753
- Ru: "Посмотреть ответ" https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17361

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We were missing a few translated localized strings. This should be fixed now, please let us know if you find any others.

Thank you for reporting! Appreciate the help.