# Unable to translate "Change inbox filter" tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, localization

It seems that in new inbox somebody forget to make "Change inbox filter" tooltip translatable.

> [image: Change inbox filter]

I can't find this sentence in [traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=inbox%20filter).

Comment: Are other tooltips able to be translated? Might be a global issue with tooltips.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard which tooltips do you mean? You can check by self on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). There is huge amount of strings translated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an oversight on our side and it affected this string in particular (it's not a global issue). It should be fixed now.

Comment: Please look at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384251/339911) as well.