# Space SE: "Question saved to На потом." Why is "for later" shown in Russian?

Tags: discussion, localization, internationalization

Moments ago I saved the Space SE question [Power and frequency units used in Deep Space Network XML data?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32329/12102) and the usual banner appeared, but with mixed English and Russian. Screenshot below at 2022-12-21 at 22:37:17 UTC.

> Question saved to На потом.

Google translate gives "На потом" → "For later".

Are others seeing this? Just me?

Glitch in the Matrix?

[image: Banner saying "Question saved to На потом." (mixed English and Russian) 2022-12-21 at 22:37:17 UTC]

Potentially related from November 30, 2022: ["All saves" and "For later" (in the interface of the saves) are not translated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384251/303080)

Comment: I've marked this as duplicate. I didn't find that question because they only showed a screenshot of the text and described it indirectly. I've added "На потом" to that question so that it is now searchable. Just another example of how showing only screenshots of critical text bits should be strongly discouraged and rectified.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/326/4179